# Broken menu bar (global menu) on gtk2 apps after installing and removing Cinnamon

Tags: unity, gui, 16.10

After installing and removing cinnamon 3, Inkscape and some other gtk2 apps like Pidgin and some others have no global menu integration. Every other gtk3 and even Qt app looks just fine. How can I fix it??? I love this App menu integration.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably (like you love the menu integration) because in cinnamon, you enable in the settings of the global menu applet, some enviroment variables and you don't see the warrning.

**Solution in this case:**

1. *If in /etc/environment file you have UBUNTU_MENUPROXY, you need to remove the line where it's if it appear and save file then. You will requiered be root (sudo), to edit this file.*
2. *Then, if in the folder /etc/profile.d/ you have a file called: "cinnamon-globalmenu.sh" remove also this file, you will requiered be root.*
3. *Reboot your machine.*

Comment: You really are looky that  i see your comment. I think not one else can tell you the same. I was how create this patch, so...

Comment: wow, I guess I'm really lucky