# Why is there duplicate menu options in global menu on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: 16.10, menu, menu-bar, globalmenu

When I open certain apps in ubuntu 16.10 I can see 2 menus appear at the top global menu bar.
For example if I open resource monitor app at the top it displays "resource monitor resource monitor".
Also in some other apps like cheese webcam at the top it says "cheese cheese".

[image: if it helps a screenshot is given below]

Comment: The theme shown in your screenshot does not seem to be the default setting of ubuntu 16.10. Please add information on any changes you might have done to change the outlook or behavior of unity/compiz/ubuntu.

Comment: i have previosly installed cinnamon desktop environment.and install global menu applet on it.After this i removed cinamon and when i came back to unity it was like this.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/879469/broken-menu-bar-global-menu-on-gtk2-apps-after-installing-and-removing-cinnamo